# Javascript/jQuery text slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to achieve a JavaScript/jQuery text slideshow, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have some text coming from 4 rows in my database and I want them to slide. I was able to make the text slide by storing my text in an array in my jQuery code, but that isn't what I want. I want the text to come from the database.

PHP/HTML

```
<div id="test">
  <?php foreach($slideshows as $slideshow): ?>
  <p id="textSlide">
    <?php echo $slideshow["testing"]; ?>
  </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>`
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var textSlider = [
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
  "Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
  "Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
];

var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  $("#textSlide").html(textSlider[i]);
  if (i == textSlider.length) {
    i = 0;
  }else {
    i++;
  }
},2000);
```

Comment: please elaborate on `come from data base`. One array for all? Each transition? Expectations are not clear. ALso any reason you can't include the data within the php loop?

Comment: Note that you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by defintiion

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your comment, I am a beginner and not very good with coding yet. I have created a database, and in that database I have some text, so I want the text that would be displayed on the page to come from my database.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with the array in JavaScript, then a simple solution is to echo the strings from PHP into the array:

```
var textSlider = [
  <?php 
      foreach($slideshows as $slideshow): 
         echo '"'.$slideshow["testing"].'",'; 
      endforeach; 
  ?>
];
```

Comment: Hello @Spencer Wieczorek thanks for your help unfortunately it still didn't work. I am getting this error in the console "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' "

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of p elements and create array with them to use in your slider code.

html/php

```
<div id="test">
  <?php foreach($slideshows as $slideshow): ?>
  <p class="textToSlide">
    <?php echo $slideshow["testing"]; ?>
  </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>`
</div>
```

js

```
var sliderTexts = [];
$(".textToSlide").each(function() {
    sliderTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```